# AFNetworking 2.0 GET Request with JSON parameters

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking-2

My backend is expecting something of format:

```
BaseURL?request={“username”:”myName”, “userEmail”:”myEmail”,”insertUserType”:”normalInsertUser”,
“password”:”myPassword”}
```

Can I use AFNetworking 2.0 to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do that:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username" : @"myName", @"userEmail" : @"myEmail", @"insertUserType" : @"normalInsertUser", "password" : "myPassword"};

NSString *urlString = @"http://sample.com";

[[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:urlString parameters:parameters];
```

Comment: So I tried doing that, but the string that AFNetworking builds is something of format BaseURL?username=myName&userEmail=myEmail&... which isn't what the backend is expecting. The params aren't written in json format.

Comment: Try this: [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters];

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use AFNetworking 2.0. For example

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];   
[manager GET:YOUR_REQUEST_URL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //Your code here
}
```

Where parameters - your `NSDictionary` with required params.

AFNetworking expects a JSON in success block.